# Waiting for character in string

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32

I am currently working on a project that will be used to test whether an instrument is within tolerance or not. My test equipment will put the DUT (Device Under Test) into a "Test Mode" where it will repeatedly send a string of data every 200ms. I want to receive that data, check is is within tolerance and give it a pass or fail.

My code so far (I've edited a few things out like .h files and some work related bits!):

```
void GetData();
void CheckData();

char Data[100];

int deviceId;
float a;
float b;
float c;


void ParseString(const char* stringValue)
{
    char* token = NULL; 

    int tokenPlace = 0; 
    token = strtok((char *) stringValue, ","); 
    while (token != NULL) { 
        switch (tokenPlace) { 
            case 0:
                deviceId = atoi(token); 
                break;
            case 1:
                a= ((float)atoi(token)) / 10.0f; 
                break;
            case 2:
                b= ((float)atoi(token)) / 100.0f; 
                break;
            case 3:
                c= ((float)atoi(token)) / 10.0f; 
                break;
        }
        tokenPlace++; 
        token = strtok(NULL, ","); 
    }
}

void GetData()
{
    int x = UART.scanf("%s,",Data);
    ParseString(Data);

    if (x !=0) {
        UART.printf("Device ID = %i\n\r", deviceId);
        UART.printf("a= %.1f\n\r", a);
        UART.printf("s= %.2f\n\r", b);
        UART.printf("c= %.1f\n\n\r", c);
    }
    if (deviceId <= 2) {
        CheckData();
    } else {
        pc.printf("Device ID not recognised\n\n\r");
    }

}

void CheckData()
{
    if (a >= 49.9f && a< = 50.1f) {
        pc.printf("a Pass\n\r");
    } else {
        pc.printf("a Fail\n\r");
    }
    if (b >= 2.08f && b <= 2.12f) {
        pc.printf("b Pass\n\r");
    } else {
        pc.printf("b Fail\n\r");
    }
    if (c >= 20.0f && c <= 25.0f) {
        pc.printf("c Pass\n\n\r");
    } else {
        pc.printf("c Fail\n\n\r");
    }
    if (deviceId == 0) {
        (routine1);
    } else if (deviceId == 1) {
        (routine2);
    } else if (deviceId == 2) {
        (Routine3);
    }
}

int main()
{
    while(1) {
        if(START == 0) {
            wait(0.1);
            GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

And this works absolutely fine. I am only printing the results to a serial terminal so I can check the data is correct to make sure it is passing and failing correctly.

My issue is every now and then the START button happens to be pressed during the time the string is sent and the data can be corrupt, so the deviceId fails and it will say not recognised. This means I then have to press the start button again and have another go. A the moment, it's a rare occurrence but I'd like to get rid of it if possible. I have tried adding a special character at the beginning of the string but this again gets missed sometimes.

Ideally, when the start button is pressed, I would like it to wait for this special character so it knows it is at the beginning of the string, then the data would be read correctly, but I am unsure how to go about it.

I have been unsuccessful in my attempts so far but I have a feeling I am overthinking it and there is a nice easy way to do it. Probably been staring at it too long now!

My microcontroller is STM32F103RB and I am using the STM Nucleo with the mBed IDE as it's easy and convenient to test the code while I work on it.

Comment: You only show the code you haven't problems with...

Comment: Can't you just always discard the first string or  get `ParseString` to return a status based on whether it sees all the expected tokens or not.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I do have problems with it. It sometimes receives the data wrong if START is pushed at the same time the string is sent. So it doesn;t work all the time.

Comment: probably it makes sense to check whether tokenPlace is big enough (i.e. all parameters were read correctly) - i.e. make some flag whether a,b,c and deviceID have good values. If not - just skip to next reading

Comment: @kaylum I'm very new with programming. Hardware is my thing, so I am afraid I'm not too sure how I would go about doing your suggestion

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I did do the if deviceId is <3 (as the ID will only be 0, 1 or 2) then show invalid ID. I did try and get it to recheck again but everything I tried either didn't compile or gave me a constant invalid ID

Comment: In `ParseString` return `tokenPlace == 4`. If the return is `0` then in `Getdata` don't call `CheckData` and don't print the error msg. Just wait for next reading.

Comment: @kaylum if I stick return tokenPlace == 4 I get a compile error. I'm likely doing it incorrectly though

Comment: Maybe you didn't change the function return type? Please have a look at the below answer. If that doesn't do what you want then please explain what other issues you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ParseString` to return a status indicating whether a complete string is read or not.

```
int ParseString(const char* stringValue)
{
    /* ... your original code ... */

    /* String is complete if 4 tokens are read */
    return (tokenPlace == 4);
}
```

Then in `GetData` use the `ParseString` return value to determine whether to skip the string or not.

```
void GetData()
{
    int x = UART.scanf("%s,",Data);
    int result = ParseString(Data);

    if (!result) {
        /* Did not get complete string - just skip processing */
        return;
    }

    /* ... the rest of your original code ... */
}
```

Comment: I still get a compile error on the return (tokenPlace ==4); it says "*Return value type does not match the function type*"

Comment: Error: Return value type does not match the function type "return(tokenPlace==4);" in "main.cpp", Line: 48, Col: 13

Comment: I'm not familiar with your dev environment so maybe it is related to your compiler. Try `return ((tokenPlace == 4 ) ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: I get the same error message again when trying that... It could very well be the compiler, I wouldn't know how to find that out though

Comment: Did you see the `int` in `int ParseString(const char* stringValue)`? Does your code have exactly that?

Comment: Ahhhhh! I still had void rather than int! Apologies, I didn't see that!

Comment: It now compiles and seems to be working. I'll have to keep testing it for a while as it didn't happen all the time before. If the issue seems to have disappeared I will be back to accept the answer. Thank you for the response and the patience. +1 is all I can offer for now until I finish testing!

Comment: I didn't want to distract you earlier but there is one thing to note about this solution. It only works if deviceid is always a single digit which from your code it seems to be. If it can be more than one digit then it will not always work and we would need a different solution such as a fixed start token.

Comment: Thank you for that note. As it stands, deviceId should only be 0,1 or 2. I cannot see it ever going further than 5

Comment: I have been unable to get it to go wrong since testing it with this new piece of code. Thank you for that, it seems to have resolved my issue.